# Union with Case?

Tags: sql, oracle, union

First of all, thank you for your time helping me!

I have the following (example) table:

UNDEAD

```
User     UserGroup     IsAdmin
_____________________________
foo      zombie        N
bar      skeletton     N
blub     vampire       Y
```

now I want something like this:

```
select UserGroup 
from UNDEAD
where User = blub
```

--> Of course, it is "vampire"

Now My Question: 
An Admin should get all groups, so the results for the different users are:

- foo --> zombie
- bar --> skeleton
- blub --> zombie, skeleton, vampire

How can I reach this goal?

Comment: What is your DBMS? IsAdmin seems to be of a boolean data type, which is not supported by many DBMS (e.g. SQL Server only knows the `bit` type).

Comment: it is oracle. The isAdmin is a Character 'Y' or 'N'. Eidted it in the question

Comment: In my opinion you need two queries: one to get the admin flag and one to get the groups. You could use an IF/ELSE clause (should be easy) or try to combine the queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT UserGroup
FROM UNDEAD
WHERE User = blub

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT UserGroup
FROM UNDEAD
WHERE 
(
    SELECT IsAdmin
    FROM UNDEAD
    WHERE User = blub
) = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `UNION` to achieve this. First, you select all non-admin users and their associated groups. Secondly you need to perform a self join that returns every group for each admin user and `UNION` the results:

```
SELECT UserName ,
       UserGroup
FROM   undead
WHERE  IsAdmin = 'N'
UNION
SELECT u1.UserName,u2.UserGroup 
FROM undead u1, undead u2
WHERE u1.IsAdmin='Y'
```

Please note that I changed the name of the `User` column as it is a reserved keyword. See below the setup script I have created.

```
CREATE TABLE undead(  
  UserName VARCHAR2(100),
  UserGroup VARCHAR2(100),
  IsAdmin VARCHAR2(100));

INSERT INTO undead(UserName, UserGroup, IsAdmin) VALUES('foo','zombie','N');

INSERT INTO undead(UserName, UserGroup, IsAdmin) VALUES('bar','skeleton','N');

INSERT INTO undead(UserName, UserGroup, IsAdmin) VALUES('blub','vampire','Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

A `union` is not necessary for this, I think.

```
select distinct UserGroup 
from undead 
where [User] = 'bulb' or (select IsAdmin from undead where [User] = 'bulb') = 'Y'
```

Herzlich Willkommen in StackOverflow aus Athen!

Answer (score 0):

You can even use a dynamic sql query.

**Query**

```
set @query = null;
set @user = 'foo';
select distinct case when `User` = @user and `IsAdmin` = 'Y'
  then 'select distinct `UserGroup` from `UNDEAD`;'
  else concat('select `UserGroup` from `UNDEAD` where `User` = ''', @user, ''';') end
into @query
from `UNDEAD`
where `User` = @user;

prepare stmt from @query;
execute  stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

Here based on the @user value the sql query will be executed. It will check for `IsAdmin`. If `Y` then all unique `UserGroup` else `UserGroup` for that particular user.

**[`SQL Fiddle demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b622/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

`SELECT *
  FROM UNDEAD S
 WHERE (CASE
         WHEN 'blub' = (SELECT DISTINCT S1.USER
                         FROM UNDEAD S1
                        WHERE S1.ISADMIN = 'Y') THEN
          'TRUE'
       END) = 'TRUE'
UNION
SELECT * FROM UNDEAD S WHERE S.USER = 'blub'`

You may change the values(blub, foo, bar) in code to check. It gives all rows for ADMIN Y, and specific for N